# IBM Mobile Quality Assurance REST API Available?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, mobilefirst-qa

Now I am working on the IBM MQA (Mobile Quality Assurance). But I want to get some informations from MQA Service such as device's information , session, bugs, .... The IBM have the rest API to support it ? Can anyone give some suggestion about this problem ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are working to improve the MQA filtering features however at this time we don't have a way to filter crashes by devices. We recently announced that MQA in Bluemix now supports integration with the following bug tracking systems: Jira, TFS, HP Quality Center, GitHub, FogBugz.

If you use one of these BTS's, its possible to use their sorting or filtering process, if any however unfortunately at this time there are no MQA APIs available.